# Flexbox that wraps at a specific length

Tags: html, css

I am designing a block of links. The idea is that links are allowed to wrap onto a new row but on smaller screens, to avoid 10's of rows, the viewable area becomes wider and scrollable.

The snippet has a `.inner-box` set to 1200px. When set to 600px, you can see the elements wrap as desired.

There is however one issue with the code as it stands.

When set to 1200px (current), the inner elements (chips) don't reach the very end, so I'm left with an empty space to the right.

What I need is shrink `.inner-box` if the inner elements don't fill the box. I've tried changing the width: 1200px to max-width: 1200px but this doesn't work.

The `.outer-box` will always remain the same width.

Any help appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 50px;
}

.outer-box {
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.inner-box {
  background-color: lime;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 1200px;
}

.chip {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 16px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <a class="chip">chip</a>
      <a class="chip">long chip</a>
      <a class="chip">chip</a>
      <a class="chip">longer chip</a>
      <a class="chip">chip</a>
      <a class="chip">longest chip</a>
      <a class="chip">long chip</a>
      <a class="chip">chip</a>
      <a class="chip">longer chip</a>
      <a class="chip">chip</a>
      <a class="chip">longer chip</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `justify-content:space-between` in `.inner-box`?

Comment: I don't  want to introduce unwanted space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Example](https://codepen.io/vfle/pen/QVqNxP)

The usage of inline-flex allows for the content to get smaller when needed.
By placing limits to the different container, we get the desired result of scrolling, but also wrapping when it is needed.

Css

```
.container{
  background: red;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.outer{
    overflow-x: auto;
  background: purple;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.inner{
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Not quite - it doesn't seem to wrap under any circumstances. I need it to start wrapping once it's reached a minimum of 1200px. For the purpose of this experiment, change the 1200px to 600px and check.

Comment: Seems to work, just gonna check it out on the actual solution.

Comment: I've rechecked and it still doesn't seem to work. The giveaway is that the red background should never been seem if scrolling is available. so, if the content is > 1200px it should wrap, if > than bounding container  (500px) it should scroll (green only), and if it is < 500 you should see the red background.

Comment: @JohnOhara Updated my solution.

Comment: Fantastic - works in chrome/firefox/edge. I don't think I would have ever thought about this config, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this style so it will not show you unwanted space.

```
.outer-box ,.inner-box {
    width: auto;
 }
```

Comment: If I apply width: auto to the inner box, it will not allow it to extend up to 1200px.